# getting components height before the mounting in React js

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I need the way to get known of the my highest  component height before rendering the table in ReactJS.
there are a lot of rows and cells, so I created virtualization for my table. 
The problem is the following,  I cut only visible in the table viewport rows and cells. But my cells have dynamic data from backend. So during scroling they expand and shrink.

Is the way to get the height before mounting? or rendering each cell in hidden component and cached the height?

Comment: Could you provide de code so I can understand better?

Comment: Why do you need height before mounting? You can use `componentDidMount` to get the height and immediately update state to trigger a rerender.

Comment: There's no height before mounting because component instance it belongs to doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the style of your row to use a state variable, you can then set this variable on CompomentDidMount. Something like the below.

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            minHeight: 0,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Or however you get height from a ref
        const fooHeight = this.elementFoo.clientHeight; 
        const barHeight = this.elementBar.clientHeight;
        const minHeight = fooHeight > barHeight ? fooHeight : barHeight;
        this.setState({ minHeight });
    }

    render() {
        const { minHeight} = this.state;

        return (
            <div style={{ 'min-height': `${minHeight}px` }} ref={elm => (this.elementFoo = elm)}>Foo</div>
            <div style={{ 'min-height': `${minHeight}px` }} ref={elm => (this.elementBar = elm)}>Bar</div>


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require a virtualized table I would recommend not reinventing the wheel and going for something like [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized).

As for just getting the rendered dimensions of a component, react-virtualized also has an HOC that you can use called [CellMeasurer](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md).